# Count the number of the same words in richtextbox

Tags: c#, user-interface, richtextbox

I want to count the words in richtextbox. First, i input a word in textbox1(for searching), and press "count" button, textbox2 will show a number about how many the same words in the richtextbox.  Here are my codes, but it doesn't work, the textbox2 always shows 0.Thank you for your help.

```
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     string a=richTextBox1.Text;
     string b=textBox1.Text;

     for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
     {

        int n=0;

        if (a.Equals(b))
        {

          n++;

        }

        textBox2.Text = n.ToString();

     }

  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare the individual word to b, not the whole sentence. You can use the following code as a reference:

```
string[] data = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
for(int i=0;i<data.Length;i++)
{
   if(data[i]==textBox1.Text)
      n++;
}
```

Comment: I think you `data[i] == textBox1.Text`

Comment: private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         string[] a=richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
         string b=textBox1.Text;

         for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
         {

            int n = 0;

            if (a[i] == textBox1.Text)
            {

               n++;

            }

            textBox2.Text = n.ToString();

         }
      }
I make it like this, but it still doesn't work. Anything wrong?

Comment: You defined and output n to textBox2 inside the for loop.Of course n would always be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
string data = richTextBox1.Text;
var target  = textBox1.Text;
var count = data.Select((c, i) => data.Substring(i))
                .Count(sub => sub.ToUpper()
                .StartsWith(target));

textBox2.Text = count;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more easier to show word count for richtextbox like this:

```
Dim wordcount As Integer
Dim a As String() = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ")
wordcount = a.Length
```

You can use 'wordcount' for the word count. For example:

```
Label1.Text = "Word Count: " & wordcount
```